# Angular set undefined value in table with OnChanges

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I don't anderstand why my value interview.InterviewID is undefined in my table :

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-interviews">
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngIf="listInterview && listInterview.length !== 0">
      <th>InterviewID</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let interview of listInterview">
      <td> 
      <input type="text" name="commentaire" id="interviewID" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="interview.InterviewID">
      </td>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

It is called in a parent component like this :

```
 <div *ngIf="personnelSelected" class="modal modal-default fade" id="modal-interviews">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
            Individual Interviews
          </h4>
        </div>
        <app-interviews [personnel]="personnelSelected"></app-interviews>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

where personnelSelected takes its value from an OnSelect method up in this parent component. This how works the interviews component :

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-entretiens',
  templateUrl: './entretiens.component.html',
  providers: [ EntretiensService ]
 })
 export class EntretiensComponent implements OnChanges{
  @Input() personnel: PersonnelInfo;
  listInterview: Interview[];

  ngOnChanges() {
   this.interviewService.get({where: 'personnelInterviewedID=' + this.personnel.id})
    .subscribe((interviews: Interview[]) => {
      this.listInterview = Interviews;
    });
   }
  }
```

the interviewService.get fonction calls the API with the where condition. But that's not the issue. I'm thinking that there is a problem with how I use the OnChanges Method but I don't figure it out yet. Could you enlight me ?

Comment: Where is the class where the interview.InterviewID variable exists?

Comment: Inside an imported model like this :
`export class Interview { 
   InterviewID: number; 
   PersonnelInterviewedID: number;
   ...;
 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-interviews">
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngIf="listInterview && listInterview.length !== 0">
        <th>InterviewID</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let interview of listInterview">
        <td> 
            <input type="text" name="commentaire" id="interviewID" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="interview.InterviewID">
        </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

your `ngFor` is outside your `ngIf` statement. So if `listInterview` is empty or null, `undefined` is the expected result

Comment: Yes, you are rigth, thanks. I've made the changes and It reveal that `listInterview` is empty, or I don't expect that. Do you have an idea why ?

Comment: One possible case is that your `where` clause doesn't query any data. Other case may be that your `service` isn't working well.

Comment: I don't think so. I wrote a `console.log(listInterview)` in the `.subscribe(){ here }` and it returns a value

Comment: `.subscribe((interviews: Interview[]) => {
      this.listInterview = Interviews;` case error at `this.listInterview` assignment?

Comment: No  `.subscribe((interviews: Interview[]) => { this.listInterview = Interviews; consol.log(this.listInterview);` I assume if the console.log return a proper value (like `{interviewID: 1, personnelInterviewedID : 342, etc...}`), the function works well.

Comment: do some test changing `OnInit` lifecycle. Suscribe at `ngOnInit()`

Comment: Ok I found it, I feel realy silly. The problem was my variable `interview.interviewID` didn't have the same name in my API so `interviewService`could'nt match them. Thank you very mutch anyway !